# Group by HTTP request parameters in a graph

Tags: graph, jmeter

I'm using JMeter and looking to do load testing on a specific URL that can use a number of parameters (like ?param=value1 then value2, then...). For the needs of testing, I have a CSV file with multiple sets of these parameters.

I have already created my request & CSV data set and when I'm running the test, I can see it runs over the different datasets. But the problem is that my graph only displays the response time for every request of the sampler, without grouping it by dataset.

I want to get a graph with multiple lines, one per dataset. E.g first data set is param1=value1, second one is param1=value2, etc.

Am I forced to create a sampler per dataset, or is it possible to have a listener do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding this `value` to your [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)'s name?

[image]

It will generate a separate Sample Result for each unique Sampler label so [Listeners](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-listeners) and the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) will display/plot the same Sampler with different "params" as different Sample Results:

[image]

Comment: So simple I missed out on it and searched for more complex ways. Thank you Dmitri!